How do I make the code execute faster (processing a image)?
In the code, I'm trying to make all the blue colors in image green. Tthe nested loop code gives the correct output, but the Numpy vectorization gives the wrong output.
np_image = np.array(image)

height, width, no_of_channels = np_image.shape

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):

        print(f' Row {i + 1}')
        print(f' Col {j + 1}')

        green_red= np_image[i, j, 1:]

        blue = np_image[i, j, 0]

        b = 2 * max(green_red)

        if blue > b:
            print(f' Pix Values -> {np_image[i, j]} = candidate pixel')
            np_image[i,j] = [0,255,0]

        else:
            print(f' Pix Values -> {np_image[i, j]} ')

i tried using numpy vectorization
blue = np_image[:, :, 0]
green = np_image[:, :, 1]
red = np_image[:, :, 2]

c = 2 * np.maximum(green, red)
d = blue > c
np_image[d] = [0,255,0]

But it is giving the wrong output.

(1) threshold -> mask (2) fancy numpy indexing that uses the mask. -- use libraries specific to the ask, such as OpenCV or diplib or skimage.

First step would be to remove the print. I am sure that is not your question, and that you expect a vectorization (it is very easy to vectorize. I haven't read the already given answer, but I am sur it does it), but it is worth mentioning that even for the very slow non-vectorized solution, printing is by far the slowest part of your code.

I also found the same solution that Jerome Richards suggest because the value of C was overflowing if it was more than 255 and it was getting converted to
"(value of c )-256" . So i just changed the type to (uint16) for performing calculation and for displaying the image converted back the to (uint8) and I was getting the right output .
I even tried Arithmetic operation on the image , I did floor division by 2 on the red,blue and green but there is a tradeoff since it decreases the contract of image.
import cv2
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()


def display_image(window_name, display_image):
  cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
  cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, 1920, 1080)
  cv2.imshow(window_name, display_image)
  cv2.waitKey()


image = cv2.imread("img.jpeg")


np_image = np.array(image)

height, width, no_of_channels = np_image.shape

blue = np_image[:, :, 0]
green = np_image[:, :, 1]
red = np_image[:, :, 2]

blue = blue.astype(np.uint16)
green = green.astype(np.uint16)
red = red.astype(np.uint16)

c = 2 * np.maximum(green, red)
d = c < blue


np_image = np_image.astype(np.uint16)
np_image[d] = [0, 255, 0]

np_image = np_image.astype(np.uint8)
display_image("changed image", np_image)
end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))


It looks like your code does not apply the condition to all pixel values. You need to apply the 'd' mask to the entire set of channels. To modify this I would do the following:
p_image = np.array(image)

blue = np_image[:, :, 0]
green = np_image[:, :, 1]
red = np_image[:, :, 2]

c = 2 * np.maximum(green, red)

d = blue > c

np_image[d] = [0, 255, 0]


i'm doing the exact same process this code is converting most of the  pixel to green

2 * np.maximum(green, red) likely cause an overflow. You should care about types. You can convert types with astype(np.uint16) for example.

Or change a bit the condition: d = np_image[...,0]//2 >= np.max(np_image[...,1:], axis=2). Not exactly equivalent: for blue=2×max(green, red), that is true, when original condition would need blue to be strictly greater than 2×max(green,red) ; Likewise, with variant np_image[...,0]//2 > np.max..., it is when blue=2×max(green,red)+1 that it is false when original version would be true. But I doubt that this criteria is that precise (it looks like some vague criteria meaning "more blue than green or red"). And it has the advantage to use less new data and more views (so less memory usage).

@JérômeRichard what if i dont want to use the extra memory?

@KamiKazE Sometimes there are tricks to avoid changing the type. Here you can divide the value rather than multiplying it as pointed by chrslg. In place operations can help too. However, one should keep in mind that Numpy create a lot of temporary array (eg. one for np_image[...,0]//2, one for np.max(...)) so Numpy if far from being conservative in memory. If you don't want such memory overhead, then Numpy is simply not the right tool. Native code, Numba, Cython can help to strongly reduce this overhead and improve speed (assuming you know a bit how CPUs work).

if the value is exceeding 255 , it is performing a ** bitwise AND** of the value and 255 , for example if value = 354 then ** 354 & 255 = 98 ** that shows as output value of c but it leads to incorrect result because most of the pixel are turned green.
